# ActionBar ignoring icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop, android-actionbar-compat

I'm slowly moving my app to Android Lollipop, in fact I'm just beginning this process.

But I'm already having some problems. The first one is that I can't make the icon appear in the ActionBar again. Just the app name and buttons appear.

Here is my style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyApp.Widget.ActionBar.Solid</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyApp.Widget.ActionBarTabStyle</item>
        <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_MyApp</item>
        <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_MyApp</item>
        <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/MyApp.Widget.ActionButton.CloseMode</item>
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_MyApp</item>
    </style>

<style name="MyApp.Widget.ActionBar.Solid" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:logo">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
        <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
        <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_MyApp</item>
        <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_MyApp</item>
        <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/MyApp.Widget.ProgressBar</item>
    </style>
```

And here is my AndroidManifest:

```xml
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MyApp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
            android:name="com.br.myapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/explore"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

        </activity>

</application>
```

And my activity class is extending ActionBarActivity from the AppCompat library v21.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following two lines in `onCreate` of your main `Activity`:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.your_actionbar_icon);
```

Comment: Have you made sure that your icon is the correct size? Icons displayed in the `ActionBar` must be of size 32x32 dp, as per the Iconography guidelines: http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#action-bar

Comment: I'm using the same launcher image. After using AppCompat 21 it is displayed bigger than before.

Comment: This might just be an implementation difference, seeings as how the Material theme for Lollipop was not designed to show the application icon in the `Toolbar`. As per the Material Design Checklist: "The app bar doesn’t have an app icon. Color and typography are used for branding instead." You could always try resizing the image and then see if that fixes your issue.